# can ninject intercept private methods?

Tags: ninject, ninject-interception

I would like to know if its possible for ninject to intercept private methods on my class. im trying to do some aop programming to dynamically inject the logging mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, all methods to be intercepted must be `virtual` [and hence not `private`].

See [this blog series by @Ian Davis](http://codepyre.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-1-the-basics/) for a flavour of what [`Ninject.Extensions.Interception`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/wiki) majors in.

Deeper AOP on the .NET platform is typically the realm of [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation), which provides hihg and low level AOP abstractions of all kinds.

Comment: i really hoped that ninject's interception project can have a documentation with those kind of information.

Comment: @Ronnel Ian Davis is a maintainer of Ninject. The initial version of the interception stuff was written by Nate Kohari and [I assume] not documented. Books can and have been written on AOP and also arguably shouldnt. You end up with pointcuts and stuff :D There was not originally a link to the blog series from the wiki but there is now. If you learn stuff, stick it on the wiki - all you need is a github account. Another big thing about Ninject and other similar projects is that everything has tests _AND CLEAN CODE_ and they tell you everything there is to know.

Comment: In other words, consider a) that the documentation b) it to be the best balance of TL;DR with solving the problem. While it's nice that there are containers with professional documentation, they dont solve all the problems in the world - the docs are not written by the devs/designers. And the doc team moves onto the next project when its finished. And then no updates happen because you'd need to PM it, implement it it and doc it. Do you really want to read a 200 page thing that talks about minutae of LinFu _AND_ DynamicProxy but omits a troubleshooting section with real world issues?